# How to show image field in Crystal Report through C# where the image path is stored in the database?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal report 11. I designed a report and set it's data through a sql stored procedure and dragged the fields that the procedure returns into the layout and everything work fine.

One of the fields returned through the procedure contains the paths to images, So in order to show these images I had to insert picture object and set it to a random image and change it's graphic location to a formula that returns the field which contains the image paths. So far good.

*This is the Design of the Report in the Crystal reports Program.*

[image]

I print preview the report and it shows the data along side with the images associated with each record, awesome!!!.

*Here is the Print Preview from the Crystal Reports Program.*

[image]

Now I want to show the report from a windows form application, I write the following code in the form that will show the report:

```
private void frmReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SupervisorBLC supervisorBLC = new SupervisorBLC();
    DataTable dataTable = supervisorBLC.M_rpt_task2();
    ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

    reportDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\msabry\Desktop\Report1.rpt");
    reportDocument.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dataTable);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;

    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    crystalReportViewer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(crystalReportViewer1);
}
```

The report shows up!, but the images not. instead of the images that have their paths returned through the dataTable I see the random Images that I set in the report.

*And this is the report when showed from my windows form application.*

[image]

**PS: When I saved the C# generated report as .rpt and opened it in the crystal report designer, I went to the graphic location of the image and I didn't find the formula I used!!!**

Comment: what helped me a lot when creating reports with images is to add the full picture path as plain text next to the images. The most common problem is that the path is incorrect or the user is missing rights. Try to add a column with the imagepath for debugging purposes. Then copy the path, and try to run it with the current user (WIN+R).

Comment: @Koryu I did added a column with the image path, and the path is correct.